# Creating a clickable background Image

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to build a website and to do so I followed [this html code](https://github.com/jordanhudgens/portfolio-html-site/blob/master/index.html) and [this css code](https://github.com/jordanhudgens/portfolio-html-site/blob/master/styles.css); this guy created a grid of 12 cool images with logos and animations, but they're not linkable. What I would like to do is to make them linkable and to do so I created this code but it's giving me weird stuff; any help please?

```
        <div class="portfolio-items-wrapper">
            <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(Immagini/Crypto.jpg)">  
                    <a href="cryptopage.html"><img src="Immagini/Crypto.jpg"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="img-text-wrapper">
                    <div class="logo-wrapper">
                        <img src="Immagini/Logo/Bitcoin.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You use "Immagini/Crypto.jpg" as a background image for the outer div and inside this div as an image. I think you should remove one - how about removing the inline style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest not making the images background images if you want to make them into links. Try this:

```
<div class="portfolio-img">  
     <a href="cryptopage.html"><img src="Immagini/Crypto.jpg"></a>
 </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.portfolio-img {
  height: 350px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this solution

```css
.click-img {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<a class="click-img" href="#" title="Clickable background image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/300/300" alt="Your Image">
</a>
```